# Why content doesn't show in UIScrollView using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, swift5

I am facing a weird issue. The content of the view controller, which is inside a scroll view, doesn't show. It only shows a dark grey screen as following

[image: yb]

### controller hierarchy

[image]

What causes this problem and how to solve it?

## [Edit]

this is the constraints

[image]

Comment: You will need to share the constraints. In order to answer this question one will need to know how the content view and scroll view are aligned and positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it's very simple.
The view controller should extends UIViewController, but I found it extending UINavigationController.

I just changed it to UIViewController.